# Persona U are U 4500 Web API

Tags: webapi, biometrics, digital-persona-sdk

I am new to biometrics. I bought a new Persona U are U 4500 Device and SDK from a vendor. The SDK has some samples (as expected). All of the samples run smoothly except the WebSample. it do not detects my device in addition it gives an error in the console.

Can anyone please help me how to fix this issue and guide me as why am i facing this problem? is it something related to my wss://localhost?

[image]

**Update**

By further diving into the program i found the specified url **https://127.0.0.1:52181/get_connection** in **websdk.client.bundle.min.js** when i opened the link it says

```
{
 "code": -2147024894,
 "message": "The system cannot find the file specified."
}
```

Am i missing some file?

Comment: Did you manage to fix your problem? And if so, could you please share your solution? I have been trying different drivers etc. and am running out of ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the solution worked for me was, one of the service wasn't running properly, Please check if DPAgent.exe is running or not. Running DPAgent.exe fixed my issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also fixed my problem eventually. The service was running fine and responding correctly. It was my Javascript code where I was calling the DP libraries incorrectly that caused my problem.

Comment: i checked the service too its working but what i need to check with DP libraries ?

Comment: @usman Please hare screenshot of the error.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:52181/get_connection is working fine for me it's showing me endpoint, web_sdk_id and web_sdk_username, etc when I open this address. But when I run app it gives "127.0.0.1:9001/connect net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

Comment: Could you share javascript SDK with me

Answer (score 0):

I don't have it in front of me now, because I switched back to the U.are.U 2.2.3 SDK, which does not have this feature.

But it sounds like you possibly have not installed the Digital Persona Lite client component. This runs a separate WebSocket service on port 9001 (IIRC) through which the JavaScript client then communicates.

It is described here: https://hidglobal.github.io/digitalpersona-devices/tutorial.html

After installation, you will need to restart.

The call to https://127.0.0.1:52181/get_connection should then respond with details of the WebSocket service, to which the JavaScript client will connect.

> NOTE: The WebSkd library requires DigitalPersona Agent running on a
> client machine. This agent provides a secure communication channel
> between a browser and a fingerprint or card device driver. The
> DigitalPersona Agent is a part of a HID DigitalPersona Workstation. It
> can be also installed with a DigitalPersona Lite Client. If you expect
> your users do not use HID DigitalPersona Workstation, you may need to
> provide your users with a link to the Lite Client download, which you
> should show on a reader communication error:

A link is provided there to download the Lite client from here: https://www.crossmatch.com/AltusFiles/AltusLite/digitalPersonaClient.Setup64.exe

Comment: Where to find Javascript SDK? I bought brand new device and did not get SDK with it.

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq It's described in the Github project, I think (first link above). Sorry, I don't have the details anymore. My client decided on a different device in the end, so I abandoned all work on the digitalPersona device.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  https://127.0.0.1:52181/get_connection is working fine for me it's showing me endpoint, web_sdk_id and web_sdk_username, etc when I open this address. But when I run app it gives "https://127.0.0.1:9001/connect net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

Comment: Could you share javascript SDK with me

Comment: Read comments above.

Answer (score -2):

you just add a script call of the following code "crossorigin = '' *". "***crossorigin='*'***". It will look like this:

```
<script src="scripts/websdk.client.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="*"></script>
<script src="scripts/fingerprint.sdk.min.js" crossorigin="*"></script>
```